# i have still face This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play how to fix

Tags: android, android-manifest

- AndroidManifest must include `com.android.vending.BILLING` permission. - **Done**
- APK is built in release mode. **Done**
- APK is signed with the release certificate(s). **Done**
- APK is uploaded to alpha/beta distribution channel (previously - as a draft) to the developer console at least once. (takes some time ~2h-24h). - **Done**
- IAB products are published and their status set to active.**Done**
- Test account(s) is added in developer console. **Done**
- Test APK has the same versionCode as the one uploaded to developer console. **Done**
- Test APK is signed with the same certificate(s) as the one uploaded to dev.console.Done
- Test account (not developer) - is the main account on the device. **Done**
- Test account is opted-in as a tester and it's linked to a valid payment method. **Done**

i dont know whats problem in my app

Comment: have you added aidl file in your project and permission in mainfiest

Comment: yes i already  added permission in mainfiest and i am using com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44 that's why no need aidl ...

Comment: have you update the .apk to production and change the version code is same as on production when you test